# What are the interesting spikes in this after-QFT graph (page 241) of Programming Quantum Computers?

Tags: shors-algorithm

I'm reading [Programming Quantum Computers](https://books.google.com.br/books?id=QqegDwAAQBAJ) trying to understand Shor's algorithm.  I learned there that we prepare a state $|x^i \bmod N\rangle$, then apply the QFT to this state.  The QFT changes the amplitudes from a uniform superposition to large amplitudes evenly spaced out by the period of $x^i \bmod N$.  For example, here's a graph of the amplitudes after applying the QFT with $N = 35$.  That's on page 241.

[image]

The book says there are 12 spikes evenly spaced.  I see a lot more than 12 spikes evenly spaced.  Should I count just the highest ones and stop when I've counted 12?  But isn't that subjective?  How would I figure out that the number is really 12 from just looking at this graph without knowing the right answer?  (In other words, how do I get 12 out of this?)

Comment: @MariiaMykhailova, you can probably answer this.  And --- thanks --- if you do!

Comment: You're right to count the local maxima.  And you're right that it's subjective, but the point is that if you run the modular exponentiation and the QFT, say, $k$ times, you'll get $x_1, x_2,\ldots x_k$, with each $x_i$ likely corresponding to one of the local maxima.  You can feed these to the classical parts of the algorithm.

Comment: That makes some sense, but it's not clear to me still.  By the way, I know the continued fraction algorithm, but it's not clear how to use it to get the period here yet.  [I asked a question on this](https://quantumcomputing.stackexchange.com/questions/14994).  Perhaps you could answer it.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Looking at the graphs you've reproduced, the left graph shows the evaluation of $2^x\bmod 35$ for $x\in\{0,\dots 63\}$ while the right graph illustrates the amplitude of the discrete Fourier transform for $\hat{x}\in\{0,\dots 63\}$.  The comment that there are "12 evenly spaced spikes" indicates that the local maxima of the right graph repeat every $64/12=5.33$ values.

You are correct, you do not have access to $\hat{x}$ in a manner that lets you observe this periodicity in $\hat{x}$ immediately; however, what you *do* have access to is a way to sample $\hat{x}_i$ for multiple $i$ in a manner that returns $\hat{x}_i$ with probability given by the (square of the) height of the respective $\hat{x}_i$.

For example, if you were to run the modular exponentiation (left graph) followed by the QFT (right graph), and sample the first register, you are likely to get a value such as $0$ with higher probability than $5$, with higher probability than $32$, with higher probability than $11$, with higher probability than $6$, etc.

From these respective samplings of $\hat{x}_i$, you can run the classical portions (the continued fraction portion) of Shor's algorithm to deduce that, indeed, there were 12 evenly spaced spikes in $\hat{x}$, giving you the period of $12$ in $2^x\bmod 35$. There are a lot of details that I'm forgetting but the point is that you use the samples from your QFT as inputs to this classical portion.